# javascript date difference

Tags: javascript, date

I've looked at: [Get difference between 2 dates in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-date-in-javascript)

And I still can't get this to work.

```
var difference = data.List[0].EndDate - Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000.0) * 1000;
var daysRemaining = Math.floor(difference / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24);
var hoursRemaining = Math.floor(difference / 1000 / 60 / 60 - (24 * daysRemaining));
var minutesRemaining = Math.floor(difference / 1000 / 60 - (24 * 60 * daysRemaining) - (60 * hoursRemaining));
var secondsRemaining = Math.floor(difference / 1000 - (24 * 60 * 60 * daysRemaining) - (60 * 60 * hoursRemaining) - (60 * minutesRemaining));
```

data.List[0].EndDate is a UTC number (like: 1291427809310 (http://www.epochconverter.com/)) that will always be later than the current date.

Comment: what are you expecting as the output?

Comment: to have the correct hours, minutes and seconds remaining.

Comment: What does "I can not get it to work" mean exactly?

Comment: I added an updated solution that takes care of dates that span across DST. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15289883/850996

Answer (score 11):

```
function days_between(date1, date2) {

    // The number of milliseconds in one day
    var ONE_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24

    // Convert both dates to milliseconds
    var date1_ms = date1.getTime()
    var date2_ms = date2.getTime()

    // Calculate the difference in milliseconds
    var difference_ms = Math.abs(date1_ms - date2_ms)

    // Convert back to days and return
    return Math.round(difference_ms/ONE_DAY)

}
```

http://www.mcfedries.com/javascript/daysbetween.asp

Comment: This doesn't take care of cases where date1 and date2 span across a day light saving change event. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15289883/850996

Answer (score 6):

I now believe *this* is the best solution:

http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 5):

You say that UTC timestamp is "2004-09-16T23:59:58.75"?

So you are basically doing

```
var x = "2004-09-16T23:59:58.75" - 123456
```

Now that you clarified that, than the above does not apply. You new issue is the number of milliseconds is in the past so when you do the difference calculation, you are getting a negative number. You probably want to swap the order around.

```
var difference = new Date().getTime()-data.List[0].EndDate;
```

Comment: sorry my bad, it's a number like 1291427809310

Comment: Added new info based on what you said in comment

Answer (score 3):

If EndDate is in milliseconds, and getTime() returns milliseconds, why do you divide it by 1000 only to multiply it by 1000 in the same line? And if you only need second precision for all the rest of the code, why work in milliseconds? Start out with a number of seconds to simplify all your calculations:

```
var difference = Math.round((data.List[0].EndDate - new Date().getTime()) / 1000);
```