# Converting a date into a description in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I want to compare a date (like `Tue, 04 Nov 2014 04:02:59 -0800`) with the current date and display as below:

> a few seconds ago
>   10 minutes ago
>   2 days ago
>   1 month ago
>   etc.

What is the most efficient way to do this in JavaScript/jQuery?

Comment: Checkout the answer here should help you out http://stackoverflow.com/a/16465436/1370442

Comment: @bUKaneer I think that question is the reverse of this one. OP there are plenty of plugins that will do this, E.g: http://timeago.yarp.com/

Comment: Another plugin which I really like is MomentJS, by far the most advanced plugin I have found. Supports lots of languages too: http://momentjs.com/

Comment: -1 for not showing any attempt to solve your own problem

Comment: @DevlshOne *`"-1 for not showing any attempt to solve your own problem"`* please, know that new users might not know exactly what's a -1 and neither how to properly format a Question. Have patience and point OP to the right direction :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript date difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435605/javascript-date-difference)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fuzzy date algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822124/fuzzy-date-algorithm)

Comment: And I'm proud of finding that one, although the answer here is frankly better.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan That's why they're directed to read the "How to ask good questions on SO" page(s) before posting, isn't it? I've been here for 4 years, no need to scold.

Answer (score 2):

I've created something that might be useful.

```js
function timeAgo(dateString){
  var postDate = new Date(dateString),
      now = new Date(),
      dif = now - postDate, // ms
      s   = Math.floor(dif/1000),
      m   = Math.floor(s/60),
      h   = Math.floor(m/60),
      d   = Math.floor(h/24),
      M   = now.getMonth() - postDate.getMonth(),
      y   = new Date(dif).getFullYear() - 1970,
      t   = ["year","month","day","hour","minute","second"],
      a   = [y,M,d,h,m,s];
  for(var i in a) if(a[i]) {a=a[i]; t=t[i]; break;}
  return a +" "+ (a>1?t+"s":t) +" ago";
}


alert("This post was created "+  timeAgo("Tue, 04 Nov 2014 16:44:07 +0100") );
```

Returns this examples

> 6 seconds ago
>   1 minute ago
>   9 hours ago
>   12 days ago
>   1 month ago
>   2 years ago

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using jQuery, I'd recommend taking a look at [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/).  It's the best date library I've been able to find so far.  You can take advantage of the `fromNow()` function which will give you the output you're looking for.

[Take a look at the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lbeqmfe7/)

```js
var data = '',
    date = new Date();

date.setYear(2012);
data += moment(date).fromNow() + "<br />";

date.setYear(2016);
data += moment(date).fromNow() + "<br />";

date.setYear(2014);
data += moment(date).fromNow() + "<br />";

$('#output').html(data);
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='output'></div>
```